# Stop nginx from serving without host

Tags: nginx

If I go to my server ip addr in my browser or with curl (ex: `curl -v http://5.5.5.5/`) nginx redirects http to https (the ip addr as host) then serves my website. Same thingh happens if I directly use `https://ip addr`. How do I stop nginx from serving unless there's a domain name? (ie https://my-domain.com)

I tried putting my domain after the 443 but nginx complains that the parameter shouldn't be there (nginx 1.18). I tried checking if there was an accidental catch all but `grep -r "_;"` got no result

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    server_name example.com;
    ...
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add new server blocks to define `default_server` example:

```
server {
    listen      80 default_server;
    listen      [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name <your IPs>;
    return      444;
}
```

444 HTTP Code mean **CONNECTION CLOSED WITHOUT RESPONSE**

Reff: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42802777/10585581